# XPath: how to select an element where the attribute value equals another element value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following xml and trying to find all the link relations within:
(xml snippet)

```
<heading nodeid="LINK_installing_driver">Installing the driver</heading>
...
<link linktotargetid="LINK_installing_driver">Installing the driver</link>
```

I can't just compare the attribute value strings, because I don't know them for sure. So I'll need a general XPath expression. I want the text of the heading whose nodeid matches the corresponding link element.

I tried the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="heading[@nodeid = //link/@linktotargetid]"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question lacks context. In general, it is best to use a **key** to lookup data from another branch of the XML document.

For example, if you define the following key at the top level of your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:key name="head" match="heading" use="@nodeid" />
```

you can then use it within the context of `link` to retrieve the value of the corresponding `heading`, e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="link">
    ...
        <xsl:value-of select="key('head', @linktotargetid)" />
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Great! Works like a charm!
Sorry for lacking context

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide more information about where the problem occurs? Your XPath looks correct, I've just created an [example](http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2C1/1) with the XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" 
              omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:value-of select="heading[@nodeid = //link/@linktotargetid]"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and for the example input XML

```
<root>
  <heading nodeid="LINK_installing_driver">Installing the driver</heading>
   <link linktotargetid="LINK_installing_not_driver">Not Installing the driver</link>
   <link linktotargetid="LINK_installing_driver">Installing the driver</link>
</root>
```

the correct heading is displayed: `Installing the driver`